# Determine datetime pattern based on locale

Tags: java, datetime, jsf

I have the following JSF code to display a date using a certain pattern.

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="E, d MMM, yyyy" timeZone="#{localeBean.timeZone}" />
```

I would like to pass the pattern to this via the localeBean also.
Is there any way to determine the specific pattern based on the locale?

```
public LocaleBean() {
  this.defaultTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
  this.strLocale = Locale.getDefault().toString();
  this.timeZone = defaultTimeZone.getDisplayName();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `DateFormat.getDateInstance`. Example:

```
   SimpleDateFormat f = (SimpleDateFormat)DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.UK);
   System.out.println(f.toPattern());

   f = (SimpleDateFormat)DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.US);
   System.out.println(f.toPattern());
```

prints:

```
dd/MM/yy
M/d/yy
```

Comment: How could I use this to also include the time in 24 hour format with the AM or PM indicator? M/d/yy HH:mm AM/PM?

Comment: you can just append it to the pattern e.g. `pattern = f.toPattern() + "HH:mm a"`

Comment: Great, works a treat. Thanks dogbane. And thanks Balus C also, I'm not sure how reputation is shared? Is it possible to give 2/3 marks to someone and 1/3 to another?

Answer (score 6):

The [`f:convertDateTime`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/convertDateTime.html) provides the `type`, `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` attributes for this which is dependent on the viewroot's locale.

Assuming Facelets:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="#{localeBean.language}"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<f:view locale="#{localeBean.locale}">
    <h:head>
        <title>SO question 4792373</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:outputText value="#{bean.date}">
            <f:convertDateTime type="date" dateStyle="short" />
        </h:outputText>
        <br />
        <h:outputText value="#{bean.date}">
            <f:convertDateTime type="date" dateStyle="medium" />
        </h:outputText>
        <br />
        <h:outputText value="#{bean.date}">
            <f:convertDateTime type="date" dateStyle="long" />
        </h:outputText>
        <br />
        <h:outputText value="#{bean.date}">
            <f:convertDateTime type="date" dateStyle="full" />
        </h:outputText>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

Here's how it renders like with English locale:

```
1/25/11
Jan 25, 2011
January 25, 2011
Tuesday, January 25, 2011
```

German:

```
25.01.11
25.01.2011
25. Januar 2011
Dienstag, 25. Januar 2011
```

Dutch:

```
25-1-11
25-jan-2011
25 januari 2011
dinsdag 25 januari 2011
```

French:

```
25/01/11
25 janv. 2011
25 janvier 2011
mardi 25 janvier 2011
```

Etc..